# Software update fails

Tags: software-updater

```
 Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

this is what I’m getting at the end when I try to update software

Answer (score 2):

Open Update-Manager and click at settings. Then A window opens. In that window at 1st TAB you will find CD-ROM option. unclick it .

I am using 12.04 , that’s why I have 12.04 there but for you it will be 12.10 . uncheck it and try again.
[image]

[image]

**Method2:**
Open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then type as

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In that file place # where ever you see the CD-ROM line .

**for example:**

[image]

Comment: Ok I will help you . click at Unity Home button , it will open Unity dash and there type as update manager and then you can do what I mentioned in the above answer.

Comment: The name "Update Manager" in 12.04 has chaged to "Software Updater" in 12.10

Comment: yeah let me know and delete these comments please . I am removing mine.

Comment: Could you accept it ?